# Angular - Add component after another (in code)

Tags: angular

I'm trying to build a re-sizable panels system with Angular.
So you can have multiple containers separated with a bar that allow the user to resize them.

For the moment I have a solution that requires the developer to write this HTML code:

```
<split-pane>
    <container>Some content</container>
    <separator></separator>
    <container>Another content</container>
    <separator></separtor>
    <container>Content ?</container>
<split-pane>
```

**split-pane**, **container** and **separator** are all custom angular2 components.
split-pane template is just

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

and I access **container** and **separtor** within **split-pane** using `@ContentChildren(ContainerComponent)` and `@ContentChildren(SeparatorComponent)`

The problem I have with this solution, is that the developper needs to manually add each **separator** between all containers.

I'd like to have a solution where the needed HTML would be :

```
<split-pane>
    <container>Some content</container>
    <container>Another content</container>
    <container>Content ?</container>
<split-pane>
```

And the **separator** components would be automatically added.
But I don't know how to do this with Angular. *Transclusion* seems to be a way to approach this but I can't wrap my head around it.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we need to load something dynamically therefore first of all we need to say angular compiler about our dynamic component like this:

```
  ...
  entryComponents: [SeparatorComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

So our desired template looks like this:

```
 <split-pane>
   <container>Some content</container>
   <container>Another content</container>
   <container>Content ?</container>
 </split-pane>
```

In order to add something between `container` elements we should get `ViewContainerRef` for each of `container`. I would do it within `SplitPaneComponent`  the following way

```
@ContentChildren(ContainerComponent, { read: ViewContainerRef }) containersRefs: QueryList<ViewContainerRef>;
```

Then just use `ComponentFactoryResolver` to get component factory and received above ViewContainers to add `SeparatorComponent` after `container` tag. Seems it should look like:

```
ngAfterContentInit() {
  this.containersRefs.forEach((vcRef: ViewContainerRef, index: number, arr: any[]) => {
    if(index === arr.length - 1) {
        return;
    }

    let compFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(SeparatorComponent);
    let compRef = vcRef.createComponent(compFactory);
    this.separators.push(compRef);
  })
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/GRl88CEl9XximbyCNCkb?p=preview)**

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks for the plunker !

Comment: Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't match your desired syntax, but by using `ngFor` you may be able to make the code shorter.

Combine `ngFor` with `last`:

```
<template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items" let-i="index" let-last="last">
  <container>{{item.content}}</container>
  <separator *ngIf="!last"></separator>
</template>
```

Define `items` in the component class, so it can obtain the data.

Comment: I don't think this would work because the content of a container could be another component.